# group by - extract all columns using sql in delphi

Tags: android, delphi, keyboard

I am an inquisitive delphi programmer.. recently, I wanted to create a android keyboard to combine native characters into it.
how can I create a custom keyboard using delphi 10.2.1 for android devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a join on subselect fior max date

```
select  l.surname, l.Name, l.result_reported_date,  l.drug1, l.drug2, l.drug3,l-drug4
from  Labresults l 
inner join  (
    Select surname, name, max (result_reported_date) max_date from labresults
    group by surname,name
)  t  on t.max_date = l.result_reported_date 
          and t.surname = l.surname
            and t.name = l.name
```